# Generic detail view View must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django

### how to access foreign key in urls.py?

```py
################models.py
...

class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='TITLE', max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField('SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True, help_text='one word for title alias.')
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Episode(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", verbose_name=("CATEGORY"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField().
...

    meta:
    ...

    def __str__(self):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("manga:episode_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.category.slug, "number": self.number})
#####################urls.py
...

    # path('category/<slug:category.slug>/<int:number>', views.EpisodeDetailView.as_view(), name="episode_detail"),
]

#################views.py

...

class EpisodeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Episode
    template_name = 'manga/episode_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'episode'
```

**
**It throwed `Generic detail view EpisodeDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`**

I wanna see Detail of Episode. but I couldn't...

I've tried throw queryset, but it doesn't work...

how to access foreign key in urls.py?
**

```
  # def get_queryset(self):
        # return Episode.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['lab'])
    def get_queryset(self):
        employee = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        print(employee)
        return Episode.objects.get(category=employee, number=self.kwargs['number'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemingly occurs in the way you designed the url pattern.
The error does suggest you use object pk or slug which means you can try to design it in a simpler way

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<slug>/', views.EpisodeDetailView.as_view(), name='episode_detail')
```